# Size of HTML and CSS page size

Tags: css, html, size

What are the various possible ways to find out the size in kbs of the HTML and CSS of a particular website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use the Net panel in [Firebug for Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/) (below), but the dev tools in Chhrome are just as nice.

Another great option is [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) by Yahoo Developer Network, which will also offer comprehensive linked recommendations for improving page results.

[Pingdom's Full Page Test](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) offers a visual without installing anything.

All of these tools will show a 'cascade', usually including info on whether a loaded resource is loading in parallel or in series (blocking the loading of subsequent resources). The various types of files loaded can generally be filtered in the display by clocking 'html' or 'css', etc above the graph.

The page load in the Net tab of Firebug:

[image: The page load in the Net tab of Firebug.]

The YSlow page test results page:

[image: YSlow page test results]

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Network tab](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) of the Web Developer tools in Chrome (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>, then select Network).

Answer (score 1):

I would use Firebug. Go to the webpage, open firebug (F12) and go to the Net tab. You got all requests made by site listed there. On the bottom of the list You got sum of all requests. You should clear browser cache before it btw, because some requests may be missing during browser cache hit.

Answer (score 1):

Opera has an "info" panel, but it only gives you the size of the HTML document requested and the total size of all inline elements (images, CSS, JavaScript, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

you find webpage file size and downloading speed also at below site tool.
http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/